# How to execute shell commands on the host machine from code running inside a vm?

Tags: php, macos, shell, laravel, osx-yosemite

I have a php codebase running in a vagrant vm running on a mac (OS X 10.10). I am trying to execute shell commands with `exec()`. The commands are evidently executed by the vm shell, but I would like the mac's shell to run it. How if possible could I achieve this? I know the other option is to run the php codebase directly onto the mac, but I was wondering.

Additional information somewhat relevant: The php codebase is [Laravel 5](http://laravel.com) and the vm is [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead). The reasons why I want to do this is to call an apple script from the mac's terminal in order to start a specific software.

Comment: what os is running in the VM?

Comment: You can use anything that lets one machine run commands on another, such as `ssh`. It doesn't matter that one machine is virtual and hosted on the other.

Comment: You're going to run into some problems depending on how the VM gets it's network from the Host. For example if your mac host is 192.168.1.112, and your VM is 10.0.1.10, the two networks will not be able to talk to each other. So if your VM gets it's own IP, like 192.168.1.113, then you can ssh just fine.

Comment: If you have a shared folder, you could create a cron job on the host to "listen" and run the commands from the VM. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just share/mount a folder between the Host and the VM, and then you could create a cron job on the Host to read and run the commands from the VM.

First you write to a file from the VM any commands you have that need to be ran on the host. Then just create a cron job on the Host (Mac) that runs every few minutes or seconds checking the file to see if there are any new commands to run. The host acts like a listener, checking and waiting to pick up any commands from the VM, to run in the host environment.

Comment: Cron job was the missing piece! Thanks.